# WinJS parsing a website using JSON

Tags: javascript, html, winjs

I'm trying to parse a website using JSON. I keep getting an error at the JSON.parse line. Here is the error I keep getting at that line:

```
    Exception is about to be caught by JavaScript library code at line 31, column 21 in ms-appx://37099737-8761-481d-b1e3-38412d272486/pages/search1/search1.js

    0x800a03f6 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character

    If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Here is my code:

```
    loadWebsite: function (totalSearch) {
        WinJS.xhr({url: totalSearch}).then(
            function (response) {
                var json = JSON.parse(response.responseText); //this line here
                var list = new WinJS.Binding.List(json.results);
                gridView1.winControl.itemDataSource = list.dataSource;
            },
        function (error){ console.log(error); },
        function (progress) { }
        );
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A website is usually sent as HTML, this looks nothing like JSON.

You should HTML parser to parse HTML, and a JSON parser to parse JSON. Makes sense, no?

Comment: I was following along Jeff Brand's tutorial here: http://vimeo.com/47884415

What exactly is JSON?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON In layman's terms JSON is a data serialization language. You use it to represent data. Like XML.

Comment: Oh ok, how would I parse the website in html?

Comment: Use an HTML parser. But, why are you parsing a website? That's not something you generally need to do. Website are made for humans, not machines. JSON is usually made for machines.

Comment: I'm retrieving search results from different websites. I don't know how else to do that

Comment: Do those websites offer an API or webservice? If so, use that.

Comment: I think most of them do have an API. I'll look into, thanks for your help!